# jQuery has() always showing that element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check to see if a `li` contains a `ul` element, but for some reason what I am doing it always says that it does contain a `ul` element. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/bT4B4/

**The HTML:**

```
<ul class="doc-nav">
    <li><a class="selected" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#getting-started">Getting Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hello-world">Hello World!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hello-world">Hello World!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("click", "ul.doc-nav a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest("li").has("ul")) {
        alert("here");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) returns a jQuery object, which is always truthy

check for `$(this).closest("li").has("ul").length`

```
$(document).on("click", "ul.doc-nav a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest("li").has("ul").length) {
        console.log("here", this, e.target);
    } else {
        console.log("here", this, e.target);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E5BMJ/)

Comment: With the `.has("ul")`, will the `ul` be the object I am working with or will it be the `li`? If it is the `ul`, all I want to do is a `slideToggle()`. So, maybe I don't want to do an `if` statement...